# Should I delete an accepted answer that is no longer correct?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

My answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/801/226 was accepted back in 2011. It was correct when I wrote it, but as software has evolved, it is now spreading false information.

I am still recieving upvotes for the answer and I'm concerned that visitors will regard the accepted answer as truth without looking at the newer, now-correct answers.

Should I delete my own answer, or is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your answer was correct when the question was asked, I would not delete it; you could not delete it, anyway, since that is an accepted answer.

What I would do is editing the answer to say something similar to "If you are using Drush version 5 or higher, it will ask you to download a module you are trying to enable, if you didn't already download it." at the beginning, so that your answer will give the most updated information. The rest of the answer is still valid, if you say "if you are using a version of Drush lower than 5, then...."

Since you know the correct answer, this is what I would do. If you feel like doing it, you could also change it to community answer, but I don't see any reason for you doing so.